# I have a few questions about ALU's....

Tags: logic, alu

So, I've been trying to learn about computers for the last few months and really learn in detail how they work. I was learning about subtractors recently and I was wondering..

First of all, to my understanding, a subtractor uses two's compliment to get a result. But, why does it subtract? for example, the two's compliment of 5 (0101) is 1011. But, that also is a positive eleven. Even though the number gets negated, what makes the subtractor take that as a negative number instead of another positive number? If the problem was 8 - 5, what stops it from doing 8 +11?
What makes it recognize a signed bit from an unsigned bit? I've heard the program running decided, but then the question would be what gives the program the ability to decide whether to add or subtract and how is that interpreted to the CPU and AlU.

Also, I've learned that AlU's use one circuit that switches forth between addition and subtraction. How does this circuit work? What makes it decide whether to add or subtract?

Lastly, how does this circuit switch from addition to subtraction? The only subtractor I've been shown is an adder with not gates attached to it? How does the circuitry differ in something that can change functions?

Answer (score 0):

Subtraction is nothing else than addition with the second operand being a negative number. Two's complement is constructed so that adding with a negative number simply works as expected (when ignoring overflow).

The ALU does not need to know if a number is positive or negative, but in two's complement all numbers with the most significant bit set to `1` is a negative number. The ALU doesn't care because two's complement is designed so that it all just works.

Now, subtraction is just addition so we can use the same circuits to carry out both functions. What the switch you are talking about does is that it negates the second operand (negation is pretty easy in two's complement, there are a few ways to do it), then it adds the numbers.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but I'm still not clear on my first question... How does taking the two's compliment work if the same number can also be added for a different result? To use the example again. The two's compliment of 5 is also a 11. So, if you were trying to do 8 - 5 through a subtractor, what in that subtractor makes it get the result of 8 - 5 instead of 5 + 11? If it doesn't need to know, then how does it produce a different result?

Comment: Sorry, but I thought of a better way to rephrase the way I think about it. Lets say I wanted to subtract 1 and 1 and put light bulbs at the end of the subtractor to represent my result. Of course, of it subtracts, neither bulb will be on. A subtractor negates the number and then adds one before adding it. So, 1 negated is 0 plus one is still 1. Since, the subtractor has the same circuitry as an adder, why doesn't it just add 1 and 1 (since those are e results after negation) instead of subtract? What makes it produce a result of no light instead (00) instead of 1 light(10) in this case?

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to tell with the lightbulb example. You say that -5 and 11 are the same number, and you may be right. But that only means 11 is too large for this particular ALU (it is an overflow). Any way, in a 4-bit system 1 is `0001` and -1 is `1111`, so `0001 + 1111 = 0000`.